# How can i add google maps to my java project with Geocoding API?

Tags: java

I'm trying to add a google map to my frame. but I'm getting an error. What is wrong in my code and am I doing it right? How to do it correctly if I have a Geocoding API Google Maps.

```
public class GoogleMapsAdd {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        JFrame test = new JFrame("Google Maps");

        try {
            String imageUrl = "http://maps.google.com/staticmap?center=40,26&zoom=1&size=150x112&maptype=satellite&key=ABQIAAAAgb5KEVTm54vkPcAkU9xOvBR30EG5jFWfUzfYJTWEkWk2p04CHxTGDNV791-cU95kOnweeZ0SsURYSA&format=jpg";
            String destinationFile = "image.jpg";
            String str = destinationFile;
            URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
            InputStream is = url.openStream();
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(destinationFile);

            byte[] b = new byte[2048];
            int length;

            while ((length = is.read(b)) != -1) {
                os.write(b, 0, length);
            }

            is.close();
            os.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }

        test.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon((new ImageIcon("image.jpg")).getImage().getScaledInstance(630, 600,
                java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH))));

        test.setVisible(true);
        test.pack();

    }
}
```

Comment: You're doing a request on the ui thread maybe?

Comment: If I visit that URL it returns just an image with the message: "The Staticmap API v1 has been deprecated as of 2009, and turned down in January 2016. The Staticmap API v2 should be used." So it looks like you're working with code from an outdated example.

Comment: You are right, I had to use this https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Europe&zoom=1&size=640x640&maptype=terrain&key=